# How Magento fulfils Product Exchange (RMA Exchange) request?

Tags: magento-enterprise, rma

I want to understand the RMA Exchange process in depth, and how it will managed by Magento? 
Lets say,

> Customer Requested for exchange product from Product-1 to Product-2?

I don't see there is option for add/edit product in already placed orders.

```
How Magento fulfills or Handle this type of request?
```

Answer (score 0):

**RMA Workflow**

1. A customer requests an RMA. Logged in customers and guests can request RMAs. You can also make a request for an RMA from the Admin.
2. After considering the request, you can authorize it partially, completely, or cancel the request. If you authorize the return and agree to pay for the return shipment, you can create a shipment order with a supported carrier from the Admin.
3. The customer returns the merchandise.
4. You receive and approve the return partially or completely, or cancel.

[image]

The Documentation for Magento RMA: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ee/user_guide/Magento_Enterprise_Edition_User_Guide.html#order-processing/return-merchandise-authorization.html%3FTocPath%3DSales%2520%2526%2520Orders%7CReturn%2520Merchandise%2520Authorization%7C_____0

Comment: Hi Brentwpeterson, you provided the workflow. I am asking the simple manner: Lets say, Customer did return the Product-1. Now my query is that how Magento/Store will serve Product-2 to customer for Product-1 returned. Magento will place new Order or in Same order this will happen? Please justify.

Comment: I don't believe that the RMA process serves a new item it only returns the old item. Have you read the documentation?

Comment: So you mean to say Customer will not get Product-2 for replacement of Product-1. or he can not do request for Replacement using RMA?